# strapi graphql plugin: how to get all records

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, strapi

#### Intent:

I need graphql to return all records

#### Issue:

`amountLimit` is implemented differently on the strapi plugin

#### Question:

Can somebody tell me why graphql `amountLimit` was implemented like this?

```js
  amountLimiting: (params = {}) => {
    const { amountLimit } = strapi.plugins.graphql.config;
    if(!amountLimit) return params;
    if (!params.limit || params.limit === -1 || params.limit > amountLimit) {
      params.limit = amountLimit;
    } else if (params.limit < 0) {
      params.limit = 0;
    } 
    return params;
  },
```

#### Explanation:

strapi has a `_limit = 0` for all records, but on graphql plugin they're adding a default limit of 100.
If I am to give `limit: -1` or `limit: 0` to the graphql query, it will put the default `limit` of `100`.
If I am to give (`else if (params.limit < 0)`)  any other `nr` lower than `0`, but it's not `-1`, the plugin queries strapi with `limit: 0` (all records)

#### Workaround

I need a way of querying graphql for all records, yet setting the limit to `-2` seems a bit random to me (as setting the limit to any `-(2^31) < nr < -1` number)

#### Solution !?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `DMehaffy (Not Strapi Employee) 12:35 PM` 
>   Strapi doesn't use the typical version system right now (it will when it goes stable)
>   unable to get all entries yes. To prevent massive queries from basically locking up your server,
>   aka DDoS. 
>   Strapi being nodejs (basically single threaded) massive one off queries is not the most effective way to pull all the data, especially in a load balancing setup
>   grab a count, divide it up, and make multiple smaller requests at the same time or asynchronously then merge the records together client side
>   Sure you are injecting a bit more round trip time, but in the long run it is quite a bit faster (especially when load balancing multiple strapi instances)

Apparently, in strapi version `beta.17.5` the negative limit will be removed completely, thus rendering this question obsolete.

As from the Strapi response up above, they are working on a solution, but at this time, for `Strapi 3.0.0-beta.14` which is my current version, the negative look-up is still available, but it will be removed, with a new solution being provided.